# UnicodeEncodeError in django app

Tags: python, django, unicode, webfaction

I'm trying to create an app using Django on webfaction. I basically was messing around with the Amazon API, and when one of the search results has a trademark symbol, which is passed to my template...the error is thrown. I'm getting the error

`Caught UnicodeEncodeError while rendering: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)`

and was wondering if anyone knew what the fix is.

Comment: We need to see the traceback and some code first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably means you are calling `str()` on a a peice of unicode data - the `str` function could be called `ascii` to better describe what it does! Your templates will be totally happy with unicode data so given that you are using Django I suspect the problem is in a `__unicode__` method or some such.

Unicode is a tricky subject, have a Google for `python unicode` to get a feel for it.

Tricky to help you further without seeing some more code but the gist is to try and use unicode strings all through your application! Python has a `unicode()` method that works exactly like the `str` method for simple strings but will work fine with unicode strings as well - it's better to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `u'\u2122'` is the trade mark sign. Somewhere in your code, you should be:

- encoding your unicode data using a codec (utf8, cp1250 to cp1258, etc) that supports that character

or

- avoiding an automatic unexpected decoding (which uses ascii, which doesn't support that character).

Which action is needed and where? No idea, as you haven't supplied a traceback ... *please* edit your question to include the full traceback, and format it as code, so that it's legible.